# How to override default page.tpl from a module, for a specific page?

Tags: theming, 7

I am coding a module which contains a "please wait" page.

On this page I need to override the default page.tpl template so I can render the "please wait" message alone without all the other regions and "site chrome".

How do I tell drupal not to use the default page.tpl and use my page-special.tpl for the specific "please wait" page ?

**EDIT**

*Please note that I am coding a module, not a theme. So everything should be done from inside the module.*

Comment: what is the path to this page?

Comment: the path is, say, /mymodule/my/path

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As per [Stuart Clark's advice](http://www.metachunk.com/comment/166#comment-166)

All you have to do is to create a template, for example : mymodule/theme/special-page.tpl.php

and add this to your module

```
function mymodule_theme(){
  return array(
    'special_page' =>  array(
      'template' => 'theme/special-page',
      'render element' => 'page'
    ),
  );
}

function mymodule_preprocess_page(&$variables, $hook) {
  if ( my_condition() ) {
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'special_page';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You see, almost every page callback declared in [hook_menu](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) is wrapped in both html.tlp.php and page.tpl.php. That's because most modules will not declare the menu item's delivery callback, and it defaults to [drupal_deliver_html_page](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_deliver_html_page/7). You can declare your own delivery callback and use a custom theme function (see [hook_theme](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7)) to render your page. It will also make overrides easier for themers.

Comment: interesting though it looks like "rooting" the problem :)

Comment: How is this like "rooting"? It is exactly the intended use of these functions and an ideal way to achieve what you are looking for from an implementation and maintenance perspective.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a  copy of `page.tpl.php` and rename it `page--node--1.tpl.php`
Then you can style the new page.
When you create the new file, remember to clear the cache.
You can find more info here http://drupal.org/node/1089656 and [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!page.tpl.php/7)

Comment: page--node--1.tpl.php will theme the output of node/1 which I doubt is the output of his custom module...

Comment: I am coding a module. Your suggestion works when your coding a theme. How do I tell Drupal to look for the page-my-path.tpl inside my module directory?

Comment: So, basically it's a transition page. In this case, you need to create a node with Please Wait. You need to rename the page.tpl.php in page--node--NID.tpl.php, clear the cache and modify the the page with you custom code. Tell us more specs.

Comment: [this page](http://drupal.org/node/104316) has a begining of an answer : "...Note for module-provided templates: A module can provide its own page template files. It is done in hook_theme()..." but I am still not getting the whole picture

Answer (score 0):

You can use this hook

```
function theme_preprocess_page(&$variables, $hook) {
$variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__special';
}
```

but you should have a tpl called page--special.tpl.php

Comment: I have implemented the hook_preprocess_page in my module and added suggestion page_wait. I have a template called page-wait.tpl.php in my module directory, (the path to my page is */wait* ) it is still not working :/

I also added this to mymodule_theme() :


`
      'page' =>  array(
            'template' => 'theme/page-wait',`
            'arguments' => array(
              'content' => NULL,
              'show_blocks' => FALSE,
              'show_messages' => TRUE,
            ),
      ),
`

Comment: I am sorry I forget that its a theme_preprocess_page you have to write it on template.php in your theme if your theme called redben so it will be redben_preprocess_page also try to make it page--wait not only page-wait and put it in template folder in your theme

Comment: Thanks I corrected the new double dash for d7. On the other hand I am not working on a theme. In fact I am working on a module... so everything should be done from inside the module

Comment: about hook_theme you can add you template beside yourmodule.info and in your code use this $items = array('data' => array('#theme' => 'page_special','#node' => $node,),
       'class' => array('page_special'),
     );
 $output = $items;return $output;

Comment: I did this and i am getting a page inside a page :D

Comment: you mean the side bars are repeated twice

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3906/discussion-between-redben-and-ahmed)

Answer (score 0):

try using this

```
function mymodule_menu()
{
 $items['test'] = array(
        'title' => t('Testing'),
        'page callback' => 'test',
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );
return $items;
}

function test()
{
    return theme('test');
}
function mymodule_theme(){
    return array(
        'test' => array(
            'template' => 'test'//name of template file, place test.tpl.php in your module
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: I am not looking for this... with your suggestion, header and footer and other regions are displayed in the output. I'd like to override page.tpl.php from withing my *module*

Comment: it seems what you want to do, can be achieved by "echo theme('test');" instead of "return theme('test');" but don't know if its good practice or not...

Answer (score -1):

I cannot find a way to override the html.tpl.php in my module. My use case was to create an "interstitial" page to display pre-roll video or an ad, similar to how forbes.com does it. Here is the user story:

"As a user, my first visit to the site will present me with an interstitial page before viewing content. WHen the page is displayed, a cookie is set in the user's browser preventing the interstitial from displaying on subsequent visits for the next 24 hours."

I created a hook_menu creating a page with a path called "welcome"

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function liveinterstitual_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['welcome'] = array(
    'title' => 'Welcome to San Angelo LIVE!',
    'page callback' => 'liveinterstitual_welcome_page',
    'page arguments' => array(),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  );
  return $items;
}
```

The page callback is liveinterstitual_welcome_page(), and it looks like this:

```
function liveinterstitual_welcome_page() {
  // If you want the sidebars and everything in the theme layer, uncomment the next line
  //return theme('liveinterstitual', array('content' => $content));
  //else, to spit out a static html page, save the page to this module's dir and do this:
  echo file_get_contents( drupal_get_path('module','liveinterstitual') . '/liveinterstitiual.html');
  //Shut down Drupal cleanly
  drupal_page_footer();
}
```

In short, I byassed the entire theme payer by piping the contents of a flat html file. Drupal has similar functions in core that do this by delivering a JSON array for ahah callbacks, for example.

I am open to other ideas, but this one appears to work for now.

Comment: Better post a question, as this is a question you are asking. Maybe check this answer here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/54733/issue-a-html-tpl-php-override-from-a-module

Comment: The answer was how I accomplished what the OP wanted. It wasn't a question.