# Define a specific page.tpl for a page create from a module

Tags: theming, 7

I have a module witch generates a custom page:

```
function my_module_basket_menu() {
  $items["my-basket"] = array(
    "title"=>"My basket",
    "page callback" => "_my_basket_page",
    "access arguments" => array("access my_module_basket content"),
  );

  return $items;
}

function my_module_basket_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'my_module_basket_page' => array(
      'template'  =>"my_module_basket_page",
      'render element' => 'page',
      'arguments' => array("listeProducts" => NULL, "key" => $key),
    ),
  );
}

function my_module_basket_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  $hooks = array('page');

  foreach ($hooks as $h) {
    // Add the module path on top in the array of paths
    array_unshift($theme_registry[$h]['theme paths'], drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module_basket'));
  }
}

function _my_basket_page() {
  // ...some treatment

  return theme("my_module_basket_page", $liste_produits, $key);
}
```

All works fine, but the problems start here: I want also to have a specific page.tpl, for example `page_my_basket.tpl.php`.

I tried to create a function `my_module_basket_preprocess_page` and change the theme there but the URL path I catch is the node of the page 404. Impossible to catch "my-basket". Any ideas? A different suggestion on how i can make it work?

**EDIT**

As suggested, i changed the name of my registry_alter function. From here when i look at the url (with a dsm()), i catch the good one, not the 404. So that part is ok.

So now i have to theme two page tpl, one for the page create in the module and a second one to replace  the page.tpl.php The problem is this second page i add a function preprocess in my module :

```
function my_module_basket_preprocess_page(&$variables, $hook){

    $alias = drupal_get_path_alias($_GET['q']);

    if ($alias == "my-basket") {
      $variables['template_files'][]  = 'page_my_basket';      
    }
}
```

In my hook_theme function, i have that :

```
function oxo_wedze_basket_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path){

  return array(
    'my_module_basket_page' => array(
      'template'  =>"my_module_basket_page",
      'arguments' => array("listeProducts" => NULL, "key" => $key)
    ),
    'page-my-basket' => array(
      'template'  =>"page_my_basket",
      'render element' => 'page'
    ),
  );
}
```

And that don't work, i still get the standard page.tpl.php

Comment: check if this link helps you http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/35280/how-to-override-default-page-tpl-from-a-module-for-a-specific-page

Comment: Your implementation of `hook_theme_registry_alter()` is not correct, it must start with your module name: `my_module_basket_theme_registry_alter()`. Please update your question after fixing this error and testing again.

Comment: Елин Й, i change the name of the function and that works well, i do not have a 404 again.

arpitr, i already see that question, but it doesn't works. I do as they say (i add the functions in my question)

Comment: In your `hook_theme` implementation check your return array. You are using dashes instead of underscores. `page-my-basket` should be corrected as `page_my_basket`.

Comment: Have you had any luck solving your problem with the provided answers?

Answer (score 5):

Page templates have overrides already available based on path.

If you see [template_preprocess_page()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7) it has this code:

```
// Populate the page template suggestions.
if ($suggestions = theme_get_suggestions(arg(), 'page')) {
  $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'] = $suggestions;
}
```

and you can see that [theme_get_suggestions()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_get_suggestions/7) looks at the path and generates the template suggestions.

This means that if you have [hook_menu()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) generate the path "my-basket" then you will be able to override its page template in your theme by naming it **page--my-basket.tpl.php** without having to do anything else, like use [hook_theme()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7) or manually add a template suggestion in the preprocessor, or alter the theme registry.

Answer (score 1):

In order to have a different `page.tpl.php` for your page rendering, you can use the `YOURMODULE_preprocess_page` hook and add `theme_hook_suggestion`.

```
function my_module_basket_preprocess_page(&$variables) 
{
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__my_basket';
}
```

The template file should be part of your theme and is located under the `/templates` folder using `page--my-basket.tpl.php` as filename. Don't forget to clear the Drupal cache.